# How to sort a Java Hashtable?

Tags: java, sorting, maps, hashtable

I inserted some data into a Java Hashtable. If I read the data from the Hashtable it doesn't come back in the same order that I inserted it in. How do I get the ordered data from the Hashtable?

I use the following code to get the values from the hashtable:

```
// Get a set of the entries
Set set = hsUpdateValues.entrySet();
// Get an iterator
Iterator i = set.iterator();
// Display elements
while (i.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry) i.next();            
    System.out.print(
        "Key : " + me.getKey()
        + ", Value: " + me.getValue()
    );
}
```

Comment: Don't use Vector, Enumeration or Hashtable. They are ancient and should be avoided. Info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453684/use-hashtable-vector-or-hashmap-or-arraylist-in-java http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601602/what-does-it-mean-when-we-say-hashtable-or-vector-is-synchronized http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873254/difference-between-a-deprecated-and-legacy-api

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you want an order-preserving map, you should use [`LinkedHashMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html):

> Hash table and linked list implementation of the Map interface, with predictable iteration order. This implementation differs from HashMap in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its entries. This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is normally the order in which keys were inserted into the map (insertion-order). Note that insertion order is not affected if a key is re-inserted into the map. (A key `k` is reinserted into a map `m` if `m.put(k, v)` is invoked when `m.containsKey(k)` would return true immediately prior to the invocation.)
>
> This implementation spares its clients from the unspecified, generally chaotic ordering provided by `HashMap` (and `Hashtable`), without incurring the increased cost associated with `TreeMap`.

Note that this is usually compared with `HashMap` rather than `Hashtable` - I don't know of an order-preserving equivalent to `Hashtable`; the latter isn't usually used these days anyway (just as `ArrayList` is usually used in preference to `Vector`).

I've assumed you want *insertion* order rather than *key-sorted* order. If you want the latter, use [`TreeMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html).

Comment: @Tester: you'd likely want to "accept" an answer, if it's okay for you :)

Answer (score 9):

Although a `Hashtable` cannot be sorted, he asked how to get sorted data, that can be done sorting the list of keys extracted from the `HashTable` and retrieving values in that order.
Something like:

```
List<'your_type'> tmp = Collections.list('your_hashtable'.keys());
Collections.sort(tmp);
Iterator<'your_type'> it = tmp.iterator();

while(it.hasNext()){
    'your_type' element =it.next();
    //here you can get ordered things: 'your_hashtable'.get(element);
}
```

will be fine.

Answer (score 8):

A `Hashtable` has no predictable iteration order, and cannot be sorted. If you only want predictable iteration order you should use a [`LinkedHashMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html). If you want to be able to sort your `Map`, you should use a [`TreeMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html).

Answer (score 8):

`Hashtable` is a legacy collection which was replaced by Java 1.2 collections in 1998. I suggest you avoid it, along with `Vector` and `Enumeration`.

Instead of `Hashtable` use `HashMap` where possible.  You can add synchronization using `Collections.synchronizedMap(map)` if you need it.

Instead of `Vector`, use `ArrayList` where possible.  You can add synchronization using `Collections.synchronizedList(map)` if you need it.

Instead of `Enumeration` you can use `Iterator` or even a `for-each` loop.

Comment: What would you use instead?

Comment: Example can be found at [link](https://www.javatpoint.com/difference-between-hashmap-and-treemap)

Answer (score 4):

Use TreeMap for sorting it:

```
Map<String, String> yourMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    yourMap.put("1", "one");
    yourMap.put("2", "two");
    yourMap.put("3", "three");

Map<String, String> sortedMap = new TreeMap<String, String>(yourMap);
```

Comment: That won't give *insertion* order though.

Answer (score 1):

> If i read the data from the hash table
>   it's not coming in the same order what
>   i inserted.

Your question does not make sense. A Hashtable does not have an "order", it is unordered (Edit: Some implementations do have an order, but it's not common for a hashtable)..

In what order would you expect the entries to be?

If you want to store elements in a certain order, you need to use a list (e.g. a subclass of java.util.List).

And BTW, your code sample does not even contain a hash table.