# sort hashtable by values

Tags: java

If I have a Hashtable  and I want to sort it by the value, i.e: integer in a descending order. How can I do this and be able to print through all of the key - value pair?

Comment: `HashTable`, or `HashMap`? Why are you using `HashTable` anymore?

Comment: Whoa, there's a class called `HashTable` in Java? I learned something new today!

Comment: Oh I wasn't talking about the capitalization -- I just never knew that one existed. :)

Comment: @Matt Ball - he might have been using Java ME, which doesn't have the Java Collections framework ... in some profiles.  But apparently not, since he's accepted a solution that depends on `Map` and `Collections`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Transfer as List and sort it:

```
    public static void sortValue(Hashtable<?, Integer> t){

       //Transfer as List and sort it
       ArrayList<Map.Entry<?, Integer>> l = new ArrayList(t.entrySet());
       Collections.sort(l, new Comparator<Map.Entry<?, Integer>>(){

         public int compare(Map.Entry<?, Integer> o1, Map.Entry<?, Integer> o2) {
            return o1.getValue().compareTo(o2.getValue());
        }});

       System.out.println(l);
    }
```

Comment: This will sort in ascending order, not descending order.  o1 and o2 should be swapped in the return of the compare function.

Comment: throws classcast exception on the return line for a Hashtable<String,Integer> and an ArrayList<Map.Entry<String,Integer>> String cannot be cast to Integer. What's wrong? cannot get it.

Answer (score 1):

SortedMap allows you to either specify a comparator, or if not use the natural ordering of elements, of which the inverse will be fine for Integers. The following prints in descending sorted order:

```
    SortedMap<Integer, Object> map = new TreeMap<Integer, Object>(new Comparator<Integer>() {
        public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
            return o2.compareTo(o1);
        }
    });
    map.put(2, "value2");
    map.put(3, "value3");       
    map.put(1, "value1");
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Object> nextEntry : map.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(nextEntry.getKey() + " : " + nextEntry.getValue());
    }
```

Comment: This answer is wrong... this explains how to sort by key.  The original question was how to sort by value.

Answer (score 0):

Hashtables are not sorted. So you need to make a copy of the hash table's key set, sort it, and retrieve the values from the hashtable by iterating through the keys in your sorted list.

Or use a sorted hash table substitute, such as TreeMap; that would avoid having to make the copy of the key set.

Comment: the value is the one which is going to be sorted.. so I need to get the key from the value... is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you really mean "how do I do this", then the answer is to just add all of them to a `TreeMap` and then iterate through it, or add all of them to an `ArrayList` and then sort it.

If you mean "how do I do this *efficiently*", I believe the answer is that it's not possible to get any more efficient than above.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333265/how-to-sort-hashtable-in-java) may have some more info.

Comment: you mean add all of the value in the hashtable to a TreeMap? if that's so then how can I print the key along with the value?

Comment: You add the values to the TreeMap using the keys already in the hashtable, then you iterate through the TreeMap's keys and print each key and value.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to below link

[Sorting HashMap by values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119366/sorting-hashmap-by-values/13913206#13913206)

or

[How to sort a treemap based on its values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448369/how-to-sort-a-treemap-based-on-its-values/13913315#13913315)

Both are implementation for sorting an hashmap based on value in ascending or descending order

Answer (score 0):

An inefficient way of doing it if you don't understand the above code.

```
public static void sortHashtable1 (Hashtable <Integer,Double> t,int count)
{
    double a[]=new double[count];
    int i=0;
    for (int ss : t.keySet())
    {
        a[i]=t.get(ss);
        i++;
    }
    Arrays.sort(a);
    outer:for(int j=a.length-1;j>=0;j--)
    {
        for(int ss : t.keySet())
        if(t.get(ss)==a[j])
        {
            System.out.println(ss+" "+a[j]);
            a[j]=-1;
            t.put(ss, -1.0);
            continue outer;
        }
    }


}
```