# Best data structure for maintaining a list of object-types sorted by frequency

Tags: data-structures, frequency, sortedlist

So, I'm going through a long list with different types of things. Let's say that it has names of different kinds of foods. The list might look something like this:

> ```
> olive
> potato
> strawberry
> potato
> potato
> strawberry
> ```

I want to store each object type and the number of times that object type occurs. Moreover, I cannot enumerate all of the object types in advance. I don't know what all of the foods will be beforehand.

I want to have something like this as the output:

> ```
> potato (3)
> strawberry (2)
> olive (1)
> ```

Basically, a list of the object types in order of their frequency. What's the best data structure for this? Are there any built-in classes in Java that I could use that would prevent me from having to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Please add the language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`HashMap<K,V>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

```
Map<String,int> map = new HashMap<String,int>();
```

Comment: But how do you sort a hashmap by values?

Comment: @dsaman123 I am not too sure, take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8119401/706456) answer. Also see the first [few enties](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=sort+hashmap+by+value) in google. You may end up using something different.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a dictionary-like structure. Then basically your algorithm would look like this:

```
-Begin Loop
    If current element not a key in dictionary:
        dictionary(element) -> 0 (Dictionary at key 'element' refers to 0)
    Else:
        dictionary(element)++ (increment dictionary at key)
```

Then you could later loop through the keys and find their frequencies.

Michael G.