# Sorting a collection of HashSets

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap

I apologize if this is a duplicate, but I couldn't find any answer that specifically answered this particular issue.

I have a HashMap that contains a string key paired with a Set value.  I want to sort the values in my map based on the length of the set.  Consider:

```
HashMap<String, Set<String>> myMap;
```

Contains:

```
{"A", {"Dukmerriot", "King", "Pumpkin"}}  
{"B", {"Steve"}}
{"C", {"Jib", "Jab", "John", "Julie"}}
{"D", {"Apple", "Amy", "Unicorn", "Charlie", "Raptor"}}
{"E", {}}
```

I want to be able to get the list `{"D", "C", "A", "B", E"}` (which designates the order of the sets from largest to smallest)  from `myMap` efficiently.

Is there a way to sort a collection of sets based on their length other than creating a wrapper class that implements Set and overriding the `compareTo` method?

EDIT: I should specify that I don't NEED to use a HashMap to maintain this collection.  I could use a TreeMap or something, but I'm not sure if that's possible since Set doesn't implement Comparable.

Comment: _"I want to be able to get the set `{"D", "C", "A", "B", E"}` from `myMap` efficiently."_ Did you mean a list? Sets are unordered, so you might as well just use `myMap.keySet()` there.

Comment: Yeah, sorry.  Essentially I just want that list in that order.

Comment: Sets can be ordered, e.g TreeSet is a SortedSet

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119366/sorting-hashmap-by-values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
final Map<String, Set<String>> map = new HashMap<>();

map.put("A", ImmutableSet.of("Dukmerriot", "King", "Pumpkin"));
map.put("B", ImmutableSet.of("Steve"));
map.put("C", ImmutableSet.of("Jib", "Jab", "John", "Julie"));
map.put("D", ImmutableSet.of("Apple", "Amy", "Unicorn", "Charlie", "Raptor"));
map.put("E", new HashSet<String>());

List<String> keys = new ArrayList<>(map.keySet());
Collections.sort(keys, new Comparator<String>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        return Integer.valueOf(map.get(o2).size()).compareTo(map.get(o1).size());
    }
});

for (String key : keys) {
    System.out.println(key);
}
```

Prints

```
D
C
A
B
E
```

I used Google Guava's ImmutableSet, just to make the code short. You might want to look at their [Multimap](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multimap) as you may find it useful.

Answer (score 6):

> Is there a way to sort a collection of sets based on their length other than creating a wrapper class that implements Set and overriding the compareTo method?

That's a completely viable way to do it. You could also use a `Comparator`:

```
List<Set<String>> mySets = new ArrayList<>(myMap.values());
mySets.sort(new Comparator<Set<String>>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Set<String> a, Set<String> b) {
        return Integer.compare(a.size(), b.size());
    }
});
```

...but now you've lost the corresponding key for each set. So let's just sort the map entries!

```
List<Entry<String, Set<String>>> entries = new ArrayList<>(myMap.entrySet());
entries.sort(new Comparator<Entry<String, Set<String>>>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Entry<String, Set<String>> a,Entry<String, Set<String>> b) {
        return Integer.compare(a.getValue().size(), b.getValue().size());
    }
});
```

and you can now "easily" get the keys:

```
List<String> sortedKeys = new ArrayList<>();
for (Entry<String, Set<String>> e : entries) {
    sortedKeys = e.getKey();
}
```

This list won't be a live view of the keys, but is going to be your best bet if that's an acceptable restriction.

Comment: do you mean "entries.sort(...)" instead of mySets?

Answer (score 0):

HashMaps are not sortable. They are optimized for looking values up by the keys.

Answer (score 0):

Since `HashMaps` don't maintain an internal order, you cannot do it like that. The best thing you can do there is getting all the values with `map.values()`, iterate over it and see which one's the longest.

```
HashMap<T, V> map = ...
Collection<V> values = map.values();

int maxLen = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
Set<String> winner = null;
for(V v : values) {
   if(v.size() > maxLen) {
     winner = v;
   }
}
```

`T` and `V` are arbitrary types. In your case, T equals String, V equals Set.

Comment: This is not sorting, this is determining the keyed value with the largest size.

Comment: Just a heads up (since I deleted my answer) my implementation neither sorted nor copied values from the map. It used a `TreeSet`, not a `TreeMap`.

Comment: This would give me the longest one, but in order to get the sorted list, this would be an n^2 operation.  I can implement a log(n) sorting algorithm for the sets while maintaining the correct order of the keys, but I was just wondering if there was a simpler way that Java gave you.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a custom object to hold both the `Set` and the `String`. Let the class implement `Comparable`, implement is usign the set size. Then just use a `List` to fill it up and `Collections.sort()` to get the desired result.

```
class A implements Comparable {
    Set set;
    String string;

    ...constructor etc....

    @Override
    public int compare(A a,A b) {
        return Integer.compare(a.set.size(), b.set.size());
    }
}
```