# Sorting based on size of ArrayList<String> in a HashMap

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, hashmap

I have a HashMap defined as follows

```
Map<String, ArrayList<String>>  map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
```

I am then storing data from databse in this hashmap and displaying the contents as follows on the console where entries towards the left of ---> are ID's and entries towards right are tags used by this ID

```
165767--->[dual-boot, windows, uninstall, ati, graphics, multiple-monitors]
6873 --->[kubuntu, re-installation]
34228--->[11.10, unity, launcher, libreoffice, icons]
```

I want to sort the ID's in descending order based on the number of tags that they have used i.e. based on **map.get(key).size()** so that the output should be ID 165767 followed by 34228 and then 6873 and so on.

I tried doing it with **TreeMap** but I am not able to figure out how to do it based on size and not the value of key and that too in descending order.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting hashmap by values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119366/sorting-hashmap-by-values). Plus, you will need a comparator that compares the lists based on their length.

Comment: Can you build the map first and then sort afterwards?

Comment: Or ... how about obtain your data already sorted from your database that you can simply translate into a HashMap?  You ought to be able to do this with SQL.

Comment: @scottb, I don't think that is preferable, and even if it is, that will only work if is a `LinkedHashMap`, since `HashMap` does not maintain order.

Comment: @scottb, bringing sorted data from database was not possible because the format of data present in database cannot be sorted.I am doing a lot of preprocessing before this to first clean the data after it is extracted from database and then using HashMap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT** :

> My output should be sorted based on number of tags and not the size of
>   ID

```
Map<String, ArrayList<String>>  map = new TreeMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();


map.put("165767",new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("dual-boot", "dual-boot", "windows", "uninstall", "ati", "graphics", "multiple-monitors")));
map.put("6873",new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("kubuntu", "kubuntu", "re-installation")));
map.put("0000000000000000",new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("test","test", "test")));
map.put("0125",new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("dual-boot", "windows", "uninstall", "ati", "graphics", "multiple-monitors")));


for(ArrayList<String> l : map.values()){
    Set<String> hs = new HashSet<>();
    hs.addAll(l);
    l.clear();
    l.addAll(hs);
}

List<ArrayList<String>> l = new ArrayList<>(map.values());
Collections.sort(l, new Comparator<ArrayList<String>>(){
    public int compare(ArrayList<String> s1, ArrayList<String> s2){
        return Integer.compare(s2.size(), s1.size());                
    }});

for(ArrayList<String> a : l){
    Iterator<Entry<String, ArrayList<String>>> iter = map.entrySet().iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> e = iter.next();
        if(e.getValue().equals(a)){

            System.out.println(e.getKey() + "-" + a);
            iter.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

Output :

```
0125-[uninstall, dual-boot, graphics, windows, ati, multiple-monitors]
165767-[uninstall, dual-boot, graphics, windows, ati, multiple-monitors]
6873-[re-installation, kubuntu]
0000000000000000-[test]
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question.My output should be sorted based on number of tags and not the size of ID.Your output looks like it is sorting based on size of ID.

Comment: yes that is what I was looking for.Thanks for help.Just a little more favour.Suppose if my Tags have possible duplicates.How can I remove them from final display?

Comment: @user2916886 In my example, there is a duplicate Tags. Not sure if I answered your question or not...

Comment: What I meant was suppose if Id 6873 has Tags list as[kubuntu,re-installation,kubuntu] then how can I remove the extra 'kubuntu' here i.e. duplicate tag in each array list

Comment: @user2916886 Check my edit. Basically, you can add the elements to an hashSet which doesn't allow duplicates and then clear the arrayList and re-add the elements of the hashset to this arrayList.

Comment: Thanks a lot!It works perfectly.Just one question.The iter.remove() in your code is the one which clears the arraylist?

Comment: Nop its remove the corresponding key value pair to the map.

Answer (score 3):

This creates a sorted list of ids.

```
List<String> sortedIds = new ArrayList<String>(map.getKeys());
Collections.sort(sortedIds, new Comparator<String>() {
    public int compare(String a, String b) {
        return map.get(b).size() - map.get(a).size();
    }
});
```

Not that you would never to maintain a `SortedMap` (like `TreeMap`), sorted on mutable values (like the length of an `ArrayList`). Since the sorted order is used to look up values, it could cause very big problems if `"id123"` became greater than `"id456"` without the Collection knowing about it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar scenario and this code worked for me (sometimes I have nulls):

```
     private static Map<Object,List<Object>> sortByArraySizeDesc(Map<Object,List<Object>> map) {
         List<List<Object>> list = new LinkedList(map.entrySet());
         Collections.sort(list, new Comparator() {
              public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) { 
                  if (o1 == null && o2 == null) { return 0; }
                  else if (o1 == null) { return 1;}
                  else if (o2 == null) { return -1; }
                  int size1 = ((List) ((Map.Entry) (o1)).getValue()).size();
                  int size2 = ((List) ((Map.Entry) (o2)).getValue()).size();
                  return size2 - size1;
              }
         });

        Map res = new LinkedHashMap();
        for (Iterator it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry)it.next();
            res.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
        return res;
    }
```