# sort a hashmap by the Integer Value desc

Tags: java, sorting

How to sort a `hashmap` by the integer value and one of the answers that I found is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21054415/how-to-sort-a-hashmap-by-the-integer-value?lq=1)

that written by ***Evgeniy Dorofeev*** and his answer was like this

```
HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    map.put("a", 4);
    map.put("c", 6);
    map.put("b", 2);
    Object[] a = map.entrySet().toArray();
    Arrays.sort(a, new Comparator() {
        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
            return ((Map.Entry<String, Integer>) o2).getValue().compareTo(
                    ((Map.Entry<String, Integer>) o1).getValue());
        }
    });
    for (Object e : a) {
        System.out.println(((Map.Entry<String, Integer>) e).getKey() + " : "
                + ((Map.Entry<String, Integer>) e).getValue());
    }
```

output

```
c : 6
a : 4
b : 2
```

my question is how the sort become **Desc** ?? and if I want to sort the `HashMap` **Asc** How can I do that ??

and the last question is : How can I have the first element after sorting?

Comment: you can probably reverse the order by switching `o2` with `o1` in the `compare` method - getting the first element is just `a[0]` and then use the same logic as in the for loop to get the value and the key!?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort a Map<Key, Value> on the values in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java)

Comment: no my question was about code that written by a user as I specified in my question :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For inverse ordering switch `o2` and `o1`. For getting the first element just access the array at index 0:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("a", 4);
map.put("c", 6);
map.put("b", 2);
Object[] a = map.entrySet().toArray();
Arrays.sort(a, new Comparator() {
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        return ((Map.Entry<String, Integer>) o1).getValue().compareTo(
               ((Map.Entry<String, Integer>) o2).getValue());
    }
});
for (Object e : a) {
    System.out.println(((Map.Entry<String, Integer>) e).getKey() + " : "
                     + ((Map.Entry<String, Integer>) e).getValue());
}        

System.out.println("first element is " + ((Map.Entry<String, Integer>) a[0]).getKey() + " : "
        + ((Map.Entry<String, Integer>) a[0]).getValue());
```

Which prints

> b : 2
>   a : 4
>   c : 6
>   first element is b : 2

If you have access to lambda expression you can simplify the sorting using those:

```
Arrays.sort(a, (o1, o2) -> 
   ((Map.Entry<String, Integer>) o1).getValue().compareTo(((Map.Entry<String, Integer>) o2).getValue()));
```

Answer (score 3):

In Java 8, you could do something like:

```
System.out.println(map.entrySet().stream().sorted((o1, o2) -> {
        return o2.getValue().compareTo(o1.getValue());
    }).findFirst());//would return entry boxed into optional which you can unbox.
```

Comment: thanx for the answer :)

Comment: No probs.. Its concise and easy to read. You dont have to do multiple conversions from object to entry and vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, answering your question: just reverse the result of `compare` method to change ASC to DESC.

```
HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
map.put("a", 4);
map.put("c", 6);
map.put("b", 2);
Object[] a = map.entrySet().toArray();
Arrays.sort(a, new Comparator() {
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        // just reverse the result of the comparison 
        return -((Map.Entry<String, Integer>) o2).getValue().compareTo(
                ((Map.Entry<String, Integer>) o1).getValue());
    }
});
for (Object e : a) {
    System.out.println(((Map.Entry<String, Integer>) e).getKey() + " : "
            + ((Map.Entry<String, Integer>) e).getValue());
}
```

But if you need to work with a sorted `Map`, I suggest you use an instance of `TreeMap` that handles the sorting by itself.

Comment: thanx very much @Orlangure