# Sort Map by Top Scores

Tags: java

I have a map that stores a players name and there score on which i update and things fine.

```
public static Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

After the first round of my game finishes i want to remove the lowest scores from the map. For instance, There could be 8 players in the map 4 of whom have a score of 10 and the other 4 have a score of 0 how would i split the map in half based on the top scorers and remove the bottom 4? Keep in mind the 8 players is not defined, it could be any number

Comment: Perhaps a `TreeMap` would be a better idea than a `HashMap` if you need sorting?

Comment: I have tried it with a tree map and can get the top 2, 3 etc with the highest scores im just not sure how to get the top half based on there scores.

Comment: Perhaps by sorting by scores and then iterating to get the first half?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119366/sorting-hashmap-by-values) that might help. One you cannot sort a Hashmap because there is no definitive order to it. If you want to sort through a *LinkedHashMap* though, this is how you do it. (A LinkedHashMap just has a definitive iterative order)

```
public LinkedHashMap sortHashMapByValues(HashMap passedMap) {
   List mapKeys = new ArrayList(passedMap.keySet());
   List mapValues = new ArrayList(passedMap.values());
   Collections.sort(mapValues);
   Collections.sort(mapKeys);

   LinkedHashMap sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap();

   Iterator valueIt = mapValues.iterator();
   while (valueIt.hasNext()) {
       Object val = valueIt.next();
       Iterator keyIt = mapKeys.iterator();

       while (keyIt.hasNext()) {
           Object key = keyIt.next();
           String comp1 = passedMap.get(key).toString();
           String comp2 = val.toString();

           if (comp1.equals(comp2)){
               passedMap.remove(key);
               mapKeys.remove(key);
               sortedMap.put((String)key, (Double)val);
               break;
           }

       }

   }
   return sortedMap;
}
```

If you want to remove the lowest value on the other hand, I doubt this is the easiest thing you could do something like this to sort them.

```
public static Entry<String, Integer> removeLowest(LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> map){
    Entry<String, Integer> lowest = null;
    for(Entry<String,Integer> e: map){
        if(lowest==null || e.getValue().compareTo(lowest.getValue()) < 0){
            lowest = e;
        }
    }
    return lowest;
}
```

PS: Don't forget to accept my answer if it works for you.

Update: If you want to remove say half of the map. You would sort it first then do this.

```
public static LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> getTopHalf(LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> map){
    LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> sorted = sortHashMapByValues(map);
    LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> out = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
    Iterator<Entry<String,Integer>> it = sorted.entrySet().iterator();
    for(int i = 0;  i<map.size()/2; i++){
        Entry<String, Integer> e = it.next();
        out.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
    }
    return out;
}
```

Comment: But what if there were more than 2 players, i want to find the half that have the highest scores then remove the other half or put the top half into a new map

Answer (score 1):

No one seems to have picked up on this not being a Mapping. If you look at high scores, names can be duplicates. What you want is an NavigableSet where

```
class HighScore implements Comparable<HighScore> {
    private static final AtomicLong NEXT_ID = new AtomicLong(1);

    protected final String name;
    protected final long id = NEXT_ID.getAndIncrement();
    protected final int score;

    // ...

    public int compareTo(HighScore o) {
        int diff = score - o.score;
        if (diff != 0) { return diff; }

        long idDiff = id - o.id;
        if (idDiff < 0) { return -1; }
        else if (idDiff > 0) { return 1; }
        else { return 0; }
    }
}
```

And then you can just `pollFirst()` to remove.

Answer (score 1):

Below is what might help you. I populated the Map with same values for key and values, to see the order when it is printed. The below example includes

- a way of getting the top half view without removing the bottom half from original map
- and also removing bottom half from original map.

Unless the requirement is to remove do not need to remove bottom half, still get the headMap that is backed by the original map.

```
import java.util.NavigableMap;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class HalfTheMap {

    static void addValues(TreeMap<String, Integer> map)
    {
        map.put("11", 11);
        map.put("33", 33);
        map.put("77", 77);
        map.put("44", 44);
        map.put("55", 55);
        map.put("22", 22);
        //map.put("66", 66);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TreeMap<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
        addValues(map);
        System.out.printf("Original Map Initial Values : %s\n",map);

        int size = map.size();
        int midIndex = (size/2) - 1;
        System.out.printf("size : %d \nmid : %d\n", size, midIndex);

        // retrieve key of middle element
        String midKey = (String)map.keySet().toArray()[midIndex];

        // Top half view of the original map
        NavigableMap<String, Integer> topMap = map.headMap(midKey, true);
        System.out.printf("Top half map : %s\n",  topMap);

        // remove the bottom half from original map.
        map.tailMap(midKey, false).clear();
        System.out.printf("Original map after bottom half removed : %s\n", map);
    }

}
```

Prints :

```
Original Map Initial Values : {11=11, 22=22, 33=33, 44=44, 55=55, 77=77}
size : 6 
mid : 2
Top half map : {11=11, 22=22, 33=33}
Original map after bottom half removed : {11=11, 22=22, 33=33}
```

I am leaving the fine tuning of halving when size is odd value to you and any other fine tuning that are appropriate to your needs.

NOTE : I have noticed that my example using keys and values of same value in each entry seems to show that it could be a solution, infact not exactly. Though it demonstrates the usage of some important methods to solve the problem.
As answered by David Ehrmann above, changing the collections to Set rather than Map and using a class that modal name and score could be a better solution.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

But there's a simplier way to do this.

You can use custom sorter algorithm on TreeMap. 
For example: TreeMap map = new TreeMap(Your own comparator);

You can write your own comparator implementing the Comparator interface.

Example (taken from StackOverflow, don't know more precisely):

class ValueComparator implements Comparator {

```
Map<String, Integer> base;
public ValueComparator(Map<String, Integer> base) {
    this.base = base;
}

public int compare(String a, String b) {
    if (base.get(a) >= base.get(b)) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 1;
    } // returning 0 would merge keys
}
```

}

Then, you only have to edit this code, to ascending order, then you only have to remove the first X. elements from.

Comment: Removing that bottom half is the problem im having