# Sort a hash map that contains double and string values

Tags: java, string, sorting, hashmap

I have been given a text file with for a winter Olympic event.
It contains team, name of competitor and score.

```
FRAMae Berenice MEITE         455.455
CHNKexin ZHANG                454.584
UKRNatalia POPOVA             453.443
GERNathalie WEINZIERL         452.162
RUSEvgeny PLYUSHCHENKO        191.399
CANPatrick CHAN               189.718
CHNHan YAN                    185.527
CHNCheng & Hao                271.018
ITAStefania & Ondrej          270.317
USAMarissa & Simon            264.256
GERMaylin & Daniel            260.825
FRAFlorent AMODIO             179.936
GERPeter LIEBERS              179.615
ect....
```

The only digit that maters is the last digit in the number. 
for each team, I need to sum their total points together and display the top 5 teams.

Code so far:

```
public class project2 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String[] array = new String[41];
    String[] info = new String [41];
    String[] stats = new String[41];    
    String[] team = new String[41];

            //.txt file location
            FileInput fileIn = new FileInput(); 
            fileIn.openFile("C:\\Users\\O\\Desktop\\turn in\\team.txt");
            //txt file to array
            int i=0;
            String line = fileIn.readLine();
            array[i] = line; i++;
            while (line != null) { 

                line = fileIn.readLine();
                array[i] = line; i++;
            }

            System.out.println(array[1]);



            //Splitting up team/competitor name/score

            for (int j =0; j< 40; j++){
                team[j] = array[j].substring (0, 3).trim ();
                info[j] = array[j].substring (3, 30).trim ();
                stats[j] = array[j].substring (36).trim ();
            }


            //random outputs ive been using fore testing.
            System.out.println(team[1]);
            System.out.println(info[1]);
            System.out.println(stats[1]);
            MyObject ob = new MyObject();
            ob.setText(info[0]);
            ob.setNumber(7, 23);
            ob.setNumber(3, 456);
            System.out.println("Text is " + ob.getText() + " and number 3 is " + ob.getNumber(7));

             for (int j =0; j< 40; j++){
                    team[j] = array[j].substring (0, 3).trim ();
                    info[j] = array[j].substring (3, 30).trim ();
                    stats[j] = array[j].substring (36).trim ();
                }


                //team and score in hashmap
                double[] statsDub = new double[40];
                for (int k =1; k < 40; k++){
                statsDub[k] = Double.parseDouble(stats[k]);
                }
                Map<String,Double> totalScore = new HashMap<>();
                for (int j =0; j< 40; j++){

                      Double tmp = totalScore.get (team[j]);
                        if (tmp != null)
                        {
                            totalScore.put(team[j], statsDub[j]+tmp);
                        }
                        else
                                totalScore.put(team[j], statsDub[j]);
                        }

                 // Get a set of the entries
                  Set set = totalScore.entrySet();
                  // Get an iterator
                  Iterator i1 = set.iterator();
                  // Display elements
                  while(i1.hasNext()) {
                     Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)i1.next();
                     System.out.print(me.getKey() + ": ");
                     System.out.println(me.getValue());








    }}}



            //if (totalScore.containsKey("COUNTRYNAME"))
            //    totalScore.put("COUNTRYNAME", totalScore.get("COUNTRYNAME") + playerScore);
            //else
            //    totalScore.put("COUNTRYNAME",0);
```

I get this output:

```
GER: 17.0
USA: 27.0
ITA: 23.0
RUS: 37.0
CHN: 20.0
JPN: 24.0
FRA: 17.0
CAN: 32.0
UKR: 10.0
GBR: 8.0
```

How could I go about only having the top 5 teams displayed in descending order?

Comment: It would be a nice exercise for Java 8 streams (if you are allowed to use them).

Comment: You have the solution in this post (second response): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119366/sorting-hashmap-by-values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create a class that implements `Comparator`, which can compare between two `Map.Entry<String,Double>` objects, based on the `Double` part.
- Create a `TreeSet<Map.Entry<String,Double>>`, which is an implementation of an ordered set, with that comparator.
- Now use the `addAll` method of the `TreeSet` to add the values from the set you got from `totalScore.entrySet()`.
- Iterate on the resulting set, keep an integer variable to count the number of iterations and stop at 5.

An alternative would be to copy the set to a `List<Map.Entry<String,Double>>` and then use `Collections.sort` to sort it. It still needs a comparator object!