# Get Hashmap Top 3 Keys

Tags: java, foreach, hashmap, integer, character

I have a  hashmap storing the number of occurrences of character in a text. I am trying to print out the top 3 occurrences, but it is printing incorrectly.

```
int max = 1000000000;
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    for (Character key : list.keySet()) {
        if (list.get(key) < max) {
            max = list.get(key);
            System.out.println(i + ": " + key + " " + list.get(key));
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, I changed it to a LinkedHashMap, but that still doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Are you trying to look at all the values, find the top three and print out their values?

Comment: can you give an example of how it's printing currently?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am trying to do.

Comment: All the values of the Hashmap printed out: t 12098
h 8692
e 17900
p 2130
r 7976
o 11459
j 45
c 2748
g 2485
u 4960
n 8377
b 1891
s 8299
x 247
f 2779
a 9863
k 1285
i 8816
l 5908
d 5014
m 4259
y 3245
w 3049
v 623
z 56
q 207

Comment: Use a `TreeMap` to sort the `HashMap` and just get the top three results. Check out this post for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java and/or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119366/sorting-hashmap-by-values

Comment: Top 3 printing out currently (incorrect): 1: t 12098
2: h 8692
3: p 2130

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could modify your program to this form:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    int max = -1;
    Character maxKey = 'a';
    for (Character key : list.keySet()) {
        if (list.get(key) > max) {
            max = list.get(key);
            maxKey = key;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(i + ": " + maxKey + " " + max );
    list.remove(maxKey);
}
```

Comment: @JeanLogeart For that matter, your answer doesn't exatly shine either. A really good solution would be based on the `PriorityQueue` class, which is a natural fit for this problem (it uses the heap data structure).

Comment: Sorting based on comparing keys in O(n log n) - this solution is O(n). I know that there is only 24 keys(number of characters) so sorting and taking top 3 will be faster in comparison to iteration 3 times.
On the other hand you could eliminate 3 iteration to the single but it will be much more complicated.
I do not claim that it is ideal but regarding intuition: I think it is simple.

Answer (score 8):

With Java 8 you can use the code below(*):

```
List<Entry<Character, Integer>> top3 = map.entrySet().stream()
                                    .sorted(comparing(Entry::getValue, reverseOrder()))
                                    .limit(3)
                                    .collect(toList());
```

<sub>(*) with the following imports:

`import static java.util.Comparator.comparing;`

`import static java.util.Comparator.reverseOrder;`

`import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;`</sub>

Comment: Upvoted. For the Java 7- verbose answer that basically does the same steps, you can see my answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to sort your entries by number of occurences and get the top 3:

```
List<Entry<Character, Integer>> entryList = new ArrayList<>(list.entrySet());
Collections.sort(entryList, new Comparator<Entry<Character, Integer>>(){
    @Override
    public int compare(Entry<Character, Integer> e1, Entry<Character, Integer> e2) {
        return e2.getValue() - e1.getValue(); // descending order
    }
});

// now let's get the top 3
List<Character> top3 = new ArrayList<>(3);
for(Entry<Character, Integer> e : entryList) {
    top3.add(e.getValue());
    if(top3.size() == 3) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using Java 8 streams, based on the one provided by @assylias. It performs the complete task of collecting character counts from a String into a Map and selecting the top 3 entries.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import static java.util.Comparator.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;

public class Stream {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final String text = "hello stackoverflow, let's count these character occurrences!";
        final char[] charArray = text.toCharArray();
        final List<Character> characters = new ArrayList<Character>(text.length());
        for (final char c : charArray) {
            characters.add(c);
        }

        final List<Entry<Character, Long>> top3 = characters.stream()
                .collect(groupingBy(Character::charValue, counting()))
                .entrySet().stream()
                .sorted(comparing(Entry::getValue, reverseOrder())).limit(3).collect(toList());

        System.out.println(top3);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[e=8, c=7,  =6]
```

Comment: It is detail but: If you know number of elements that you want to put to the `ArrayList` why you do not initialize `ArrayList` with proper size and get rid of resizing?

Comment: I don't know the size beforehand. Strings can contain any of the >1 million UTF-8 characters but typically will contain much less.

Comment: Hm, but in your example you are iterating over array of characters, right? So you know the size of array. As a result you could initialize `characters ` list with proper size. Am I wrong?

Comment: Oh sorry, you meant the first ArrayList. Yes, that one can be sized to the length of the String but I would consider that a premature optimization which clutters the code. Probably a matter of opinion, I do recall that Sonar is indicating this as an issue lately.

Comment: So I added the initialCapacity to please @baju and Sonar