# Finding the Key from Value in Map

Tags: java, treemap

So I am having a bit of trouble understanding how to do this. I am building a word counter in Java using `Map<String, Integer>` where a word is the `String` and the amount of times that word was said in a .txt document is `Integer`. This is all working great...but I am trying to develop a part where it will display at the bottom what the top 5 results are ---> what the top 5 `map.values()` are.

The problem I have run into is after I find the value, I can't get the String with it.

Any suggestions would be very helpful to me.

Comment: `Map<String, Integer>` is named wordCount

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `Map.Entry<String, Integer>` to get the pair of the key and value.

The `values()` method returns only values, whereas the `keySet()` method returns only the keys.

Firstly, you should sort your map, based on values, to get the top five results.
The straightforward approach uses a `Comparator`. See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32891575/2869791) for more.

Then you simply get the first five entries of the `map.getEntrySet()`. It would be easier to use an `Iterator` for this.

UPDATE:

```
    Set<Entry<String, Integer>> set = wordCount.entrySet();
    List<Entry<String, Integer>> list = new ArrayList<Entry<String, Integer>>(set);
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>() {
        public int compare(Map.Entry<String, Integer> o1, Map.Entry<String, Integer> o2) {
            return o2.getValue().compareTo(o1.getValue());
        }
    });

    int topResults = 5;
    Iterator<Entry<String, Integer>> iter = list.iterator(); //refer the sorted collection
    while (iter.hasNext() && topResults > 0 ) {
        Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry = iter.next();
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "->" + entry.getValue());
        topResults --;
    }
```

Comment: Your code only tells what the values are for the first 5 values. Doesn't actually show the highest value, then the 2nd highest, etc

Comment: This piece of code is to be used after you do a Collections.sort, using the comparator based approach, as shown in the linked answer.

Comment: I placed above what I tried, it still didn't work, did I do it wrong?

Comment: There was a small mistake. The `Iterator` was still on the original map, which was not sorted. The `list` collection is the sorted collection. Hence, the iterator should point to `list`. And that solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

a) Iterate over the map, this way you have both keys and values accessible:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    Integer value = entry.getValue();
    // ...
}
```

b) build a second map for reverse lookup, e.g. Map - note that this is likely not a good idea here as you may have duplicate keys (same number for different words)

c) consider using a bidimap - this is a map which you can query both by key and by value.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to override `Comparator` and build your Map constructor based on it.
Code is showed below:

```
class ValueComparator implements Comparator {
    Map map;

    public ValueComparator(Map map) {
        this.map = map;
    }

    public int compare(Object keyA, Object keyB) {
        Comparable valueA = (Comparable) map.get(keyA);
        Comparable valueB = (Comparable) map.get(keyB);
        return valueB.compareTo(valueA);
    }
}

public class YourClass{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        map.put("a", 10);
        map.put("b", 30);
        map.put("c", 50);
        map.put("d", 40);
        map.put("e", 20);
        System.out.println(map);

        Map sortedMap = sortByValue(map);
        System.out.println(sortedMap);
    }

    public static Map sortByValue(Map unsortedMap) {
        Map sortedMap = new TreeMap(new ValueComparator(unsortedMap));
        sortedMap.putAll(unsortedMap);
        return sortedMap;
    }

}
```

Comment: [*"What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?"*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321/2891664) Your `ValueComparator` will also delete entries with duplicate values.