# A program that counts the letters in string in Java

Tags: java

I have to create a program that counts the letters in string and I have a little problem with that.

This is my code in `main`:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String str;
int count;

System.out.println("Enter some text: ");
str = sc.nextLine();

char ch;

System.out.println("Letters: ");
for (ch = (char) 65; ch <= 90; ch++) {
    count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if (ch == str.charAt(i) || (ch + 32) == str.charAt(i)) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    if (count > 0) {
        System.out.println(ch + ": " + count);
    }
}
```

Everything looks fine, but the output **should not** be in alphabetical order, rather ordered by the number of letters descending.

For example, if you input *Hello World*, the output should be something like this:

> L: 3
>   O: 2
>   H: 1
>   D: 1
>   E: 1
>   R: 1
>   W: 1

The output would be sorted in descending order of letter frequency. That means the most frequent letter should appear first and the least last.
The order for letters that appears in equal proportions must be in alphabetical order.

Comment: When I run your program, I get the expected result. And the code looks good as well.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Something like this: L: 3
O: 2
H: 1
D: 1
E: 1
R: 1
W: 1  In nonalphabetical order

Comment: Why such output is expected? You count letters in alphabetical order, why do you expect output not to be?

Comment: I think u told actual output.. I mean what should be the output

Comment: It looks like he wants them to be sorted in descending order of letter frequency, but I don't get what's the order for letters of equal frequency. I would have guessed order of apparition, but then the E would be before the D

Comment: D: 1
E: 1
H: 1
L: 3
O: 4
R: 1
W: 1
 This is the output I get when I run

Comment: This is the output: D: 1
E: 1
H: 1
L: 3
O: 2
R: 1
W: 1 It's in alphabetical order. I won't to be like this. I want to be like i wrote in the post :)

Comment: You should have worded the question that way!

Comment: @Sisi except it's hard to get what you want from a single example. Sure that's the output for "hello world", but what should the output for "goodbye world" be? Or "Hello, World!" ? It's best if you can put the reasoning in words in addition to one or more examples

Comment: Why you want the output so? Yes put more inputs and outputs... Expected and Actual

Comment: @Sisi to help you edit your post : can you confirm you want the output to be sorted in descending order of letter frequency? That means the most frequent letter should appear first, and the least last. Also, what should the order be for letters that appears in equal proportions? Why must the D appear before the E ?

Comment: @Aaron Yes, that's what i want.

Comment: And what about letters with the same frequency? Maybe you just don't care about their order?

Comment: @Sisi : Posted an approach. try whether it's feasible

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your outer loop browse the letters in alphabetical order, and that's where you display the count.

I would instead recommend browsing the input string with a single loop, updating the count of each letter in a `Map<Character, Integer>` as I encounter them.
Then once the input `String` has been consumed, I would sort the `Map` by descending values, and print each key/value pair.

```
Map<Character, Integer> lettersCount = new HashMap<>();

for (int i=0; i <str.length(); i++) {
    Character current = str.charAt(i);
    if (Character.isLetter(current)) {
        Integer previousCount = lettersCount.get(current);
        if (previousCount != null) {
            lettersCount.put(current, previousCount + 1);
        } else {
            lettersCount.put(current, 1);
        }
    }
}
List<Map.Entry<Character, Integer>> list = new LinkedList<Map.Entry<Character, Integer>>( lettersCount.entrySet() );
Collections.sort( list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<Character, Integer>>()
{
    public int compare( Map.Entry<Character, Integer> o1, Map.Entry<Character, Integer> o2 )
    {
        return (o2.getValue()).compareTo( o1.getValue() );
    }
} );
for (Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entry : list) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " : " + entry.getValue());
}
```

You can try it out [on ideone](http://ideone.com/NN1eWA).

As you can see, sorting a `Map` by values isn't trivial :-/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort the results then you'll have to store the results & then iterate over them by their count descending to print in order

The best data structure to store them into would be a heap, keyed off of count. Java supplies such a data structure as java.util.PriorityQueue which can take a comparator function which first compares count & then character

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str;
        int count;

        System.out.println("Enter some text: ");
        str = sc.nextLine();

        char ch;

        System.out.println("Letters: ");
        LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> charCountMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
        for (ch = (char) 65; ch <= 90; ch++) {
            count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
                if (ch == str.charAt(i) || (ch + 32) == str.charAt(i)) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            if (count > 0) {
                System.out.println(ch + ": " + count);
                charCountMap.put(ch + "", count);
            }

        }
        LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> sortedMapBasedOnValues = sortHashMapByValues(charCountMap);

        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : sortedMapBasedOnValues.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("Key : " + entry.getKey() + " Value : " + entry.getValue());
        }

    }
    // Following method used from
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119366/sorting-hashmap-by-values

    public static LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> sortHashMapByValues(LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> passedMap) {
        List<String> mapKeys = new ArrayList<>(passedMap.keySet());
        List<Integer> mapValues = new ArrayList<>(passedMap.values());
        Collections.sort(mapValues, Collections.reverseOrder());
        Collections.sort(mapKeys);
        LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        Iterator<Integer> valueIt = mapValues.iterator();
        while (valueIt.hasNext()) {
            Integer val = valueIt.next();
            Iterator<String> keyIt = mapKeys.iterator();

            while (keyIt.hasNext()) {
                String key = keyIt.next();
                Integer comp1 = passedMap.get(key);
                Integer comp2 = val;

                if (comp1.equals(comp2)) {
                    keyIt.remove();
                    sortedMap.put(key, val);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return sortedMap;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Robert : Sorry for that. Formatted it. :)