# Selecting top 'n' entries in a sorted HashMap

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap

I have already looked at sorting a HashMap by value [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119366/sorting-hashmap-by-values) but I'm not quite sure how to extract top 'n' entries of this sorted HashMap. Or is there a better way of accomplishing this?

To provide some overview, I'm working on a P2P project and I maintain a mapping between peerID and the corresponding rate at which files can be downloaded from each of those peers. Then I need to select top 'n' peers with highest download rates.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Once you have the `LinkedHashMap` in the correct order, just iterate over the values and take the first (or last depending on the sort order) _n_ entries.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23846961/1553851

Comment: You should review https://stackoverflow.com/q/109383/18157 as wel

Comment: You might consider using [PriorityQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) over sorting `HashMap`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Obviously a `TreeMap` with a custom comparator would be a better choice, especially since it has a method that is specifically tailored for this: `headMap(Key k)` which will give you all the entries *up to this key*.

On the other hand if you insist on the `HashMap` you could use java-8 for this:

```
yourMap.entrySet()
       .stream()
       .sorted(Comparator.comparing(e -> e.getValue(), Comparator.reverseOrder()))
       .limit(n)
       .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));
```

Comment: Hi Eugene! You know, there's no method that returns the top/bottom n entries in TreeMap. tailSet and headSet return a subset view that is either higher than or lower than the given value. You have to go the stream way for this, there's no other option.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner there is something I am missing probably in your comment... I am referring to `headMap` and it does return a view indeed... isn't what the OP is asking for here?

Comment: Hey Eugene. My point is that there's no way to select top n entries from a TreeMap, with n being a fixed number. headSet returns a view of the entries lower than a given value (not lower than a given index). That was my point. You'll find that there's no straightforward way to return a submap view of fixed size; you have to stream the entries and use limit(n) and collect to a new map. (This is why I have upvoted your answer).

Comment: @DachuanZhao am I supposed to guess what is happening from your comment?

Answer (score 2):

I think you might consider using the `TreeSet` class instead of the `HashMap` so you can always have them sorted. To access the 'n' you could use the Iterator or the `subSet()`, `tailSet()` methods, depending on what you need.

Comment: There's no method that returns the top n entries, neither in TreeSet nor in TreeMap. tailSet and headSet return a subset view that is either higher than or lower than the given value.