# Top 5 Highscore list java using sharedpreferences

Tags: java, hashmap, sharedpreferences

I'm new to Java and to this forum and I hope you can help me out;
I'm working in Android Studio and I would like to keep and display a Top 5 highScore list in my application.

For everytime someone finish the game I get the score and firstname of the player;

```
private void saveScore(){
String firstname = mPreferences.getString(PREF_KEY_FIRSTNAME, null);
int score =mPreferences.getInt(PREF_KEY_SCORE, 0);


//add name and score to map and save in shared preferences

Map<String,Integer> highScores=new HashMap<>();
    highScores.put(firstname, score);
    for (String s : highScores.keySet()) {
        prefHighscore.edit().putInt(s, highScores.get(s));
    }
    prefHighscore.edit().apply();

}
```

I then want to access the map in my ScoreActivity
    private void getScores() {

```
    HashMap<String, Integer> map= (HashMap<String, Integer>) 
prefHighscore.getAll();
    for (String s : map.keySet()) {
        Integer value = map.get(s);
```

}

I hope this code is allright. I now get stuck because I would like to:

1.sort the list and get five highscores.
2.get the name and score for the five and display them

Can you give me some hints?

Comment: For sorting the list, you can just [bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort#Analysis). The basic idea is that you run through all the numbers (with a for loop) and swap the number and the number after it if the number after it is smaller than the number. Repeat that process until the list is sorted.

Comment: You can maybe try this to sort a hashmap by values https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119366/sorting-hashmap-by-values/13913206

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Is there anyway to sort out five keys and values from the hashMap even though it contains more than five? Or do I have to make sure that my map only holds 5?