# Group JAVA Map keys based on tokens in string key

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, treemap

I have this requirement where I need to parse a text file and extract n-grams from it and store the n-gram mapping with their count in a map. Now, the Map key is string which can have 1,2,3 words in it.

> e.g. ("mango", 10), ("facbook friend", 6), ("the rich guy", 3) 1<=n<=3

Example mapping:

("mango", 2)

("apple", 1)

("mango tree", 5)

("facebook friend", 3)

("facebook people", 8)

("Bougth new watch", 2)

Now, I want to sort the map based on keyword tokens length in map key. like all 1 word key mapping should be first in map then 2 words then 3 words mapping.

I tried using TreeMap but the main challenge was to define **compareTo** function for the sorting order. Any ideas? Like below method do not work.

```
    Map<String, Integer> m = new TreeMap<>(Comparator.comparingInt(k -> k.split(" ").length));

    m.put("mango tree", 5);
    m.put("Bought new watch", 2);
    m.put("apple", 1);
    m.put("mango tree", 5);
    m.put("Bought new watch", 2);
    m.put("appl1", 1);
    m.put("mango 1", 5);
    m.put("Bought 1 watch", 2);
    m.put("appl2", 1);
    m.put("mango 2", 5);
    m.put("Bought 2 watch", 2);
    m.put("appl3", 1);
    System.out.println(m);
```

Output: {apple=1, mango tree=5, Bought new watch=2}

Comment: what is the problem in defining your own compareTo, you will have to compare in the basis or number of spaces in your string but not the length thats all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119366/sorting-hashmap-by-values

Comment: @viveksinghggits if i only define the compareTo based on number of spaces then the map will have only 3 mappings.

Comment: @Santosh I need to sort based on words in a key, Not on the string value.

Comment: How can you have two map entries with the same key? I.e. ("facebook friend", 3) and ("facebook friend", 8) is not possible, right?

Comment: @shash678 updated example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code inserts the records in order.

```
    SortedMap<String, Integer> m = new TreeMap<>(new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
            int s2length = s2.split(" ").length;
            int s1length = s1.split(" ").length;
            return s2length>s1length?-1:s2length==s1length && s2.equals(s1)?0:1;
        }
    });

    m.put("mango tree", 5);
    m.put("you have to check this out too", 1);
    m.put("apple", 1);
    m.put("apple", 5);
    m.put("you have to check this out", 1);
    m.put("check this out", 1);
    m.put("Bought new watch", 2);
    m.put("check this out too", 1);

    System.out.println(m);
```

Comment: Try adding more values. This will only store 3 mappings.

Comment: Yes. I missed a condition. Please check the updated code.

Comment: Yes, this seems accurate.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `Collectors.toMap` with an ordered map supplier like so:

```
Map<String, Integer> m = new HashMap<>();
m.put("mango tree", 5);
m.put("Bought new watch", 2);
m.put("apple", 1);

LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> sortedMap = m.entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(e -> e.getKey().split(" ").length))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                Map.Entry::getValue,
                (o1, o2) -> o1,
                LinkedHashMap::new));

System.out.println(sortedMap);
```

**Output**

```
{apple=1, mango tree=5, Bought new watch=2}
```

---

You can also use the following `.sorted(...` line:

```
.sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey(Comparator.comparingInt(k -> k.split(" ").length)))
```

Comment: I was thinking of some creative way of using compareTo so that we have a sorted map at the time of insert but this solves problem.

Comment: @quintin ah, now I know what you mean. See my update above.

Comment: I don't think new TreeMap<>(Comparator.comparingInt(k -> k.split(" ").length)); would work

Comment: Try adding more than 3 mappings. That is what the behavior of copmareTo is.

Comment: ok, I added 4 and it still works.. you must be making some mistake

Comment: How can appl2 and appl3 are missing from the map then? That is what the original problem was

Comment: ah, sorry!! I'll remove that part from the answer