# How to sort a HashMap based on values in descending order?

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap

I'm trying to sort a `HashMap` based on *values*, so that its ordered in *descending order*. But I have no idea on how to implement it. How would I go about doing it?

```
HashMap<K, Integer> keysAndSizeMap = new HashMap<>();

for (K set : map.keySet()) {
     keysAndSizeMap.put(set, map.get(set).size());
}

// implementation here?

System.out.println("keysAndSizeMap: " + keysAndSizeMap);
```

Example of the result I want:

- input: `{800=12, 90=15, 754=20}`
- output: `{754=20, 90=15, 800=12}`

-or-

- input: `{"a"=2, "b"=6, "c"=4}`
- output: `{"b"=6, "c"=4, "a"=2}`

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119366/sorting-hashmap-by-values

Comment: do you need java-8 solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting HashMap by values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119366/sorting-hashmap-by-values)

Comment: A `HashMap` does not have an intrinsic order.  You have to sort the elements and put them into a `List` or `LinkedHashMap` in the order in which you want them to appear when iterated.  By definition a `HashMap`'s iteration order is undefined.

Comment: Ah, so you are looking for a _histogram_?

Comment: Are you ordering by keys or by values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way of sorting a map by values using streams API. Note, the resulting map is a `LinkedHashMap` with descending order of its values.

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(1, 10);
map.put(12, 3);
map.put(2, 45);
map.put(6, 34);
System.out.println(map);

LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer> map2 = 
    map.entrySet()
       .stream()             
       .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder()))
       .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(), 
                                 e -> e.getValue(), 
                                 (e1, e2) -> null, // or throw an exception
                                 () -> new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer>()));

System.out.println(map2);
```

*Input*: `{1=10, 2=45, 6=34, 12=3}`

*Output*: `{2=45, 6=34, 1=10, 12=3}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TreeSet` with custom comparators to sort the entries and Java 8 streams to create the sorted map.

```
TreeSet<Entry<T, Integer>> sortedEntrySet = new TreeSet<Entry<T, Integer>>((e1, e2) -> e2.getValue() - e1.getValue());
sortedEntrySet.addAll(keysAndSizeMap.entrySet());
Map<T, Integer> sortedMap = sortedEntrySet.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));
```