# How to sort an ArrayList using a Map key as list object and value as the order?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I need to keep the order of my list of objects as it can be changed and reordered anytime in my webapp.

In my model I have a array list of objects example

```
objectList = [object1, object2, object3, object4]
```

and I save the order of each object belonging to this instance to a Map example:
order

```
{
   "object1":4,
   "object2":2,
   "object3":1,
   "object4":3
}
```

Therefore i want to sort my array according to its value in the map retrieved by the objects Id as the key:

Expected result:

```
[object3, object2, object4, object1]
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Do you mean something like this: `objectList.sort(Comparator.comparing(o -> yourMap.get(o.getid()));`?

Comment: you can try to read this article. I think the answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119366/sorting-hashmap-by-values

Comment: @Lino Boy that was quick. Yes this works great thank you. Can you post it as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your objects have a getter for the id `getId()`, then you can make use of the [`Comparator.comparing()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-) helper method, which creates a comparator for the provided lambda:

```
objectList.sort(Comparator.comparing(o -> yourMap.get(o.getId()));
```

This effectively the same as writing your own `Comparator` or writing your own compare method.

Answer (score 0):

Something that may look overkilling but it could be more natural to define a new class

```
class IndexedElement implments Comparable<Integer> {
    private final int index;
    private final YourObject element;

    public IndexedElement(int index, YourObject element) {
       this.index = index;
       this.element = element;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Integer o) {
       return this.getIndex().compareTo(o.getIndex()) ;
    }
}
```

storing objects like that in a `TreeSet<IndexedElement>` you can automatically achieve the sorting and retrieving (TreeSet.ceiling(new IndexedElement(yourIndex, null)), just remember to Override the equals/hashCode in IndexedElement)